# putting a variable inside another variable's name

Tags: php, variables, foreach

So I have an array of numbers:

```
$number=range(0,50)
```

I have a foreach loop which looks like this:

```
foreach($number as $row){
    $special($row[0])function=<insert special number function>
}
```

As I tried to visualise, I am trying to put a variable, the number, inside another variable's name, unfortunately, unsuccessful. Hoping you could help me :)

edit:
    I am trying to make 50 slightly different variables, the only difference is the number. So I want to create something as follows:

```
$special1function
$special2function
$special3function
...
$special50function
```

Comment: What's your goal? Creating 50 functions for 50 numbers is almost certainly not what you want to do. There are better ways to get things done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use variable variables in php : view in [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

For example:

```
${"special" . $counter."function"} = "your custom value";
```

but it's better to using an array inested : [Array](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: If there is 50 custom (numbered) values, generated by a loop, creating 50 variables is a bad solution. Much better is using an array.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked. I am not really working with variables generated by a loop, this was just to make my problem more simple. I really have a database, containing n rows( around 20), each row gets 4 different variables, which will later on be put in an array and from there into a table. But all those details are not relevant for my question, and would only make it more difficult for you to understand.

Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

if im understanding you write, try this:

```
     $special = array();
     foreach($number as $row){
         $special[$row['youre row name that you want']] = $number;
     }


     print_r($special);
```

Comment: I am trying to make 50 slightly different variables, the only difference is the number. So I want to create something as follows:

$special1function
$special2function
$special3function
...
$special50function

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array:

```
$specialFunctions = array();
foreach(range(0,50) as $number){
    $specialFunctions[$number] = <insert special number function>;
}
```

Then, access the 23rd one like this:

```
$twentyThird = $specialFunctions[23];
$twentyThird(); // call the function
```

But most likely, you will need to iterate over them:

```
foreach($specialFunctions as $specialFunction) {
    $specialFunction(); // call the function
}
```

Creating 50 variables, as suggested by other answers, is not a good solution.